# How to make Tesseract OCR output words in a sentence form?

Tags: c#, tesseract

[image: Sample Image Input]

The result I get is like this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM0qG.png

Is it possible to make Tesseract give an output in sentence/paragraph form like this?

> This is to certify that you have successfully PASSED the PHIL-IT General Certification Examination held on January 26, 2015 at the Cebu Institute of Technology - University, N. Bacalso Avenue, Cebu City 6000 Philippines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `result` is a `List` of `Tessnet2.Word`, and the text of each `Word` it is stored in its `item.Text`, you can:

1. Create a list with only the words (not the full `Tessnet2.Word` object)
2. Join this list, using "space" as the separator

So let's say your results are stored in a var named `result` (you performed the operation 
`var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, null);`). If you combine both steps, it looks like this:

```
string phrase = string.Join(" ", result.Select(x => x.Text).ToList());
```

The result is:

> This is to certify that you have successfully PASSED the Phil-lT
>   General Certification Examination held on [nnuag 26, 2015 at the Cebu
>   Institute uf Tedmnlngy · University , N. Bacalso Avenue, Cebu City
>   6000 Philippines.

(it has some detection errors, but that is a different issue)